# What Spring Rest Annotation handles a page load event?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, quickbooks-online

I'm looking at all of the spring rest annotations, but I want that is triggered when the page is loaded?  Is it any of these, or something else entirely.  I am using a REST Model View Whatever approach.

```
org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeSave (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.RepositoryEventHandler (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleAfterDelete (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeRenderResources (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleAfterLinkSave (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeLinkSave (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleAfterSave (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeLinkDelete (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.RestResource (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeDelete (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.ConvertWith (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleAfterLinkDelete (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
    org.springframework.data.rest.repository.annotation.HandleBeforeRenderResource (implements java.lang.annotation.Annotation)
```

I need for something to happen in Java when the page loads.

```
@RepositoryEventHandler(myObject.class)
public class myIntuitObjectEventHandler {

com.intuit.ipp.data.myIntuitObject[] mio;

    @Autowired
    private myObjectRepository myObjectRepository; 


    @HandleAfterCreate
    public void handleBeforeCreate() {

        logger.out("Handle Before Create!");

    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean when page loads - if you have a rest service that needs to be invoked, call it using javascript in window.onLoad()

Comment: How do I do that?  Is there more documentation on how to do rest services

Answer (score 0):

Option #1: Use a request mapping for when you GET the page. That way it is called each time your user makes a request to that controller. For example, each time your user hit **localhost:8080/yourApp/yourService** then the below method would be called.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/yourService", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String someMethod() { . . . };
```

Option #2: Make the service call via the client side with an AJAX call on either of the below events depending on what you need.

```
$(window).load(function() { . . .});
$(document).ready(function(){ . . . });
```

Comment: Where is the best place to find information on REST?